# How to dynamically add a reify property to a Python3 object

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to do some advanced wizardry and I don't completely understand the problem which is no doubt why I'm having trouble solving it.

If I do something super hacky and let the child (`DailyPic`) know about it's parent (`Site`) then I can make everything work, but I can't figure out how to dynamically do this just from `Site`.

I'm trying to dynamically add the fantastic [reify](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/_modules/pyramid/decorator.html#reify) (slightly modified) to `DailyPic` but have the `DailyPic` instance call a method on an instance of `Site`.

hacky but it works

```
class reify():
    def __init__(self, wrapped, name=None):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

        if name is None:
            from functools import update_wrapper
            update_wrapper(self, wrapped)
        else:
            self.wrapped.__name__ = name

    def __get__(self, inst, objtype=None):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        val = self.wrapped(inst)
        setattr(inst, self.wrapped.__name__, val)
        return val

class Site:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def mk_filename(self, pic):
        self.counter += 1
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}-{self.counter}.{pic.ext()}"

    def save(self):
        pic = DailyPic()

        from functools import partial
        pic._mk_filename = partial(self.mk_filename, pic)

        return pic


class DailyPic:
    def ext(self):
        return 'gif' # simplified for example

    @reify
    def filename(self):
        return self._mk_filename() # YUCK!!!

# works but ugly...

class Site1(Site): pass
class Site2(Site): pass

pic1 = Site1().save()
pic2 = Site2().save()

print(pic1.filename) # Site1-1
print(pic2.filename) # Site2-1
```

I'm trying to get to something like this:

```
class Site:
    def save(self):
        pic = DailyPic()
        DailyPic.filename = reify(
            functools.partial(lambda pic: self.mk_filename(pic)),
            'filename'
        )
        return pic

# sorta works...

print(pic1.filename) # Site2-1 , should be Site1-1
print(pic2.filename) # Site2-2 , should be Site2-1
```

If an advanced wizard could chime in that would be fantastic!

Comment: what are you generally trying to do here? download pictures from a site? and name them with counters? in your goal example, it's unclear where `pic1` and `pic2` come from, so it's hard to tell what you want...

Comment: Yes, I've cut out lots of extra code (like Site.save really takes a url) but what I'm trying to accomplish isn't really the point. I'm asking how to dynamically add `reify` (probably applicable to `property`) with proper instance bindings.

Comment: i think it's relevant, this sounds a lot like an XY problem, but it's tough to tell. i mean, it's kinda weird that the order in which you access `filename` determines a file's name.

Comment: Yes, it's a very weird order, that's why I'm trying to do the reify trickery. ;)

Answer (score 1):

unless you really, really, need it to be a property, just ignore reify and properties and set a function on each instance that overwrites itself when run once.

```
class Site:
    def save(self):
        pic = DailyPic()

        def filename(pic_self):
            val = self.mk_filename(pic_self)
            pic_self.filename = lambda _: val
            return val

        pic.filename = filename
        return pic
```

then it's just:

```
print(pic1.filename())
```

if you really want it to be a property you could always set `pic._filename = filename` and have a property on `DailyPic` that returns `self._filename()`. which is basically what you were doing to begin with.